# How to do the equivalent of a vlookup in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hope you all can give me a hand with this powershell question.

So what I need is to do a get-childitem on a directory and collect a lot of information from the properties from this cmdlet and store it into something like a hastable. But for one property of the resulting hastable, I need that data to be filled in by grabbing the value of a property from an import-csv generated object--matched on a value from my first object.

So like

```
PSObject A (from GCI)
$name = a.fullname
$extension = a.extension
$height = (go look in object b and find the height value for where a property (lets say fullname) of object a matches)

PSObject B (from import-csv)
B.height
B.fullname (this is what I want to match on object a)
```

I know this probably isn't the best formatted question but it's the best I can do without having to explain other weird parts of my code.

Thank you

Comment: Search for merging 2 sets of objects using a hashtable of one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind your script not being extremely efficient, you can use this as your blueprint:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem your/path/here 
$csv = Import-Csv your/csv/here.csv

foreach($item in $items)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $item.FullName
        Extension = $item.Extension
        Height = $csv.Where({$item.FullName -eq $_.FullName}).Height
    }
}
```

**Note**

- This blueprint assumes that the CSV has a header with name `FullName` and another header with name `Height`
- We're using `-eq` which would be an exact match, however you should consider which operator is better for your script. For that, rely on [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1)
- `Height` will be empty if there are no matches, meaning, there is no `FullName` from `Get-ChildItem` that is an exact match with the items on `FullName` from your CSV.

Comment: Good to know, happy to help @Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of merging two sets of objects using a hashtable.  It's faster than searching the 2nd set every time.

```
$a = 'name,address
joe,here
john,there
james,far' | convertfrom-csv

$b = 'name,phone
joe,555
john,556
james,557' | convertfrom-csv

$b | % { $hashB = @{} } { $hashB[$_.name] = $_ }

$a | % { [pscustomobject]@{
           name=$_.name
           address=$_.address
           phone=$hashB[$_.name].phone # lookup phone by name
         }
       }
```

```
name  address phone
----  ------- -----
joe   here    555
john  there   556
james far     557
```

Comment: I actually didn't use this because I was too lazy to handle possible duplicated values hehe